# java cannot send emails from one account of linux server

Tags: java, email, tomcat, smtp, exim

I have a dedicated server that hosts many websites. One of them cannot send emails. All of them have a Tomcat/MySQL app that sends emails when a user clicks a button. This was working without any problem for years, however, today one account/website stopped being able to do it.

On the Tomcat console I get this exception:

`There was an unexpected error.com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.xxxxxxxx.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Port 26 is defined globally in Exim mail server configuration, and if I try to connect using telnet, I can do it to other accounts from the server, however, I can't do it with this particular account.

so if I try:

`telnet mail.myfirstdomain.com 26`
it connects successfully,

but if I try:

`telnet mail.myotherdomain.com 26`
it doesn't work.

I've been all day trying to figure out where this SMTP outgoing port is configured locally, but I've had no luck yet.

This is the code of the java class that sends emails, it's the same on all the other websites, and it was working perfectly until today on this particular website:

```
        java.util.Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);

        // Construct the message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set the from address
        Address fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        message.setFrom(fromAddress);

        // Parse and set the recipient addresses
        Address[] toAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(to);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,toAddresses);

        // Set the subject and text
        message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        message.setText(text, "UTF-8");

        Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
        trans.connect(smtpHost, mailUsr, mailPwd);
        message.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        message.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7bit");
        message.saveChanges();

        trans.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        trans.close();

        sentStatus = true;
```

In the /etc/exim.conf file, there's this line:
daemon_smtp_ports = 26 : 587 : 465 : 25

so, as you can see, port 26 is there, and well, as I mentioned before, all the other websites are working without a problem.

I just haven't been able to find out where to enable port 26 for this particular account.

Any help will be truly appreciated. I'm aware that there are many questions related to this subject, however, none of them has been useful in my particular situation.

I have total access to the server, WHM, CPanel, SSH

Regards!!

Comment: I am a bit confused, your error log entails port 25, but you&#39;re writing with regard to port 26.
Is this just a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo, that's the error message I get. For what I've read, port 25 is used internally by exim mail server, but the port 26 is the one used for outgoing emails. I can connect to all the other domains from my server using telnet and port 26, but I can't do it for this particular domain

Comment: I forgot to mention that using webmail app (squiremail etc.), I'm actually able to send emails from this website. Any clue? anybody?

Comment: Ok, so my intuitive first thought would be: what has been changed recently? Because you mentioned that everything worked for years before.

Comment: actually it was working 2 days ago. I didn't make any changes, I was out of town, so I guess some automatic update on the server caused this. What I've just done, and it seems to be working, was to change the mail.smtp.host, so insted of using mail.websiteDomain.com, I'm using the server's domain. This fixed my problem, however, I still don't know why all of this happened.

Comment: Nice to hear. Is the subdomain `mail` configured/set on this tomcat instance? If not it would be one obvious reason this did not work before (although I doubt this, because you mentioned all other servers are running, using the same config and they are working properly).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157357/discussion-between-david-artmann-and-sergio).